# How to hide AppBar dynamically on Double Tap?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to dynamically hide and show App Bar on DoubleTap on Container with some animation on hiding, but the solution from this link doesn't work for my project: [Flutter - How can I dynamically show or hide App Bars on pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53941362/flutter-how-can-i-dynamically-show-or-hide-app-bars-on-pages)

Image of the app: 
[image]

Code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GeneratedCouponScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  bool ShowAppBar = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: ShowAppBar ? AppBar(
        title: Text('Makdolan Flutter'),
      ) : null ,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: GestureDetector(
        onDoubleTap: () {
          ShowAppBar = false;
        },
        child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text('DATA WYDANIA:', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
                  Text('10/09/2019', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text('UNIKALNY KOD:', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                  Text('e-86-tC-9', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
                ],
              )
              ],
            ),
            Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                Image.asset('assets/images/coupon_hamburger.png',)
              ],
            )
          ],
        )
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't the linked solution work for your project? Also, you need to wrap `ShowAppBar = false;` in a call to `setState`.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work. I tried to show a Toast message on Double Tap and it worked, but it doesn't work for my App Bar. When it comes to setState, I cannot call this method, because my Widget is Stateless. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Yes... make your widget a `StatefulWidget` and not a `StatelessWidget`. You can't change the data and/or appearance of a `StatelessWidget` dynamically within the widget itself. (That's what "Stateless" means.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `setState`

```
onDoubleTap: () {
  setState(() => ShowAppBar = false); // you missed setState
}
```

**Update (Full code):**

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: YourPage()));

class YourPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _YourPageState createState() => _YourPageState();
}

class _YourPageState extends State<YourPage> {
  bool _showAppBar = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: _showAppBar ? AppBar() : null,
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onDoubleTap: () => setState(() => _showAppBar = !_showAppBar),
          child: Container(
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I cannot call setState. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get that, you weren't able to call `setState` or you don't want to call `setState`?

Comment: I wasn't able to call setState. That's what I mean. The IDE throws this error: "The method 'setState' isn't defined for the class 'GeneratedCouponScreen'"

Comment: Ah I see, you are using `StatelessWidget` class, do one thing, hover your mouse to `StatelessWidget` and press `option/alt + enter/return` key, and IDE would show you to convert it to `StatefulWidget`. After that you can use `setState`

Answer (score 2):

Change **Widget** type **Stateless** to **Stateful Widget**

Note: setState() work with statefull widget

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home:
     App(),
    ),
  );
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {

  bool showAppBar = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: showAppBar ? AppBar(
          title: Text('Makdolan Flutter'),
        ) : null ,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: GestureDetector(
          onDoubleTap: () {
            setState(() {
              showAppBar = true;
            });
          },
           child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text('DATA WYDANIA:', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
                          Text('10/09/2019', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
                        ],
                      ),
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text('UNIKALNY KOD:', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                          Text('e-86-tC-9', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                      Image.asset('assets/images/coupon_hamburger.png',)
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              )
          ),
        ));
}
}
```

Comment: Great! That worked like a charm, but how to animate hiding the App Bar? Do you have a clue how to do it?

Comment: @szakes1 yes just checkout  "AnimatedContainer" for animation

Comment: Do you know how to wrap AppBar with AnimatedContainer widget? Using it on AppBar, it throws an error saying that it needs the AppBar widget. Do you know how to do it?