# How i can hide and show app bar with animation flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Here is my code

```dart
return Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(
            appBar:getIsShowAppBar(layoutProvider.currentIndex, 
              realEstatesProvider) ? AppBar (),

            child: IndexedStack(
                children: layoutProvider.screens,
                index: layoutProvider.currentIndex),
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(), );
```

Comment: Can you describe more about your code, what went wrong while running current code? What and how you like to switch visibility ?

Comment: Try This : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65960645/15732885

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to show an app bar and hide it when you want you would want to use the SliverAppBar widget witch allows you to make an app bar of your choice and allows to dissapear it when scrolling and other options with animations. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html

Comment: thank i used CustomScrollView and sliver app bar and it works

Comment: Great to hear, if it helped pls make the answer answered.