# How to animate hiding AppBar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need help with animating my AppBar.

My AppBar hides on DoubleTap, but there's no animation in it, it hides immediately. I want it to be animated. I tried to wrap my AppBar with SlideTransition and AnimatedContainer widget, but none of these work, because the error says I need a PreferredSize widget.

I would be extremely glad, if someone helped me!

I already checked out this answer, but the guy, who answered to this question, has the same problem. There's no animation.  [Show (slide in) or hide (slide out) flutter AppBar on screen tap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53490116/10551887)

Here's the video of my AppBar: 
https://streamable.com/it7ib

Here's the photo how my AppBar looks like: 
[image: flutter]

Code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GeneratedCouponScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GeneratedCouponScreenState createState() => _GeneratedCouponScreenState();
}

class _GeneratedCouponScreenState extends State<GeneratedCouponScreen> {

  bool showAppBar = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: showAppBar ?  AppBar() : null ,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: GestureDetector(
        onDoubleTap: () {
          if (showAppBar) {
            setState(() {
              showAppBar = false;
            });
          } 
          else {
            setState(() {
              showAppBar = true; 
            });
          }
        },
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text('DATA WYDANIA:', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
                      Text('10/09/2019', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text('UNIKALNY KOD:', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                      Text('e-86-tC-9', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
                    ],
                  )
                  ],
                ),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                    Image.asset('assets/images/coupon_hamburger.png',)
                  ],
                )
              ],
            )
      ),
    )));
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53490116/show-slide-in-or-hide-slide-out-flutter-appbar-on-screen-tap

Comment: Yes, I also found this answer, but the guy, who answered to this question, has the same problem. There's no animation in his AppBar and he did the same as me. I should have pointed out that I already found that answer.

Comment: So you can use PreferredSize widget:

```
appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50.0), // here the desired height
          child: AppBar(
            // ...
          )
        ),
```
I think you would be able to animate your appBar after applying PreferdSize widget

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way of doing it is by using stack and AnimatedBuilder.

[image]

```
class GeneratedCouponScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GeneratedCouponScreenState createState() => _GeneratedCouponScreenState();
}

class _GeneratedCouponScreenState extends State<GeneratedCouponScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: _controller,
          builder: (context, child) => Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Transform.translate(
                offset: Offset(0, -_controller.value * 64),
                child: Container(
                  height: 56.0,
                  child: AppBar(
                    title: Text('Title'),
                    leading: Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_back,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onDoubleTap: () {
                  if (_controller.isCompleted) {
                    _controller.reverse();
                  } else {
                    _controller.forward();
                  }
                },
                child: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 56.0),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'DATA WYDANIA:',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                              ),
                              Text('10/09/2019',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
                            ],
                          ),
                          Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text('UNIKALNY KOD:',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                              Text('e-86-tC-9',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                          Image.network(
                            'http://via.placeholder.com/640x360',
                          )
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for answering now after some time, but I still have a question. After hiding this AppBar, how do I move the content below upwards?

Comment: Well, there are multiple ways. One way could be to translate all widgets just like app bar.

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this with **animated container** widget. We have to make a custom AnimatedAppBar widget that manages the animation.

```
  class AnimatedAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget { //implements PreferredSizeWidget
  const AnimatedAppBar({super.key, required this.showAppBar});

  final bool showAppBar;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      // when showAppBar value is true appbar will show with animation
      // when showAppBar value is false appbar will hide with animation
      height: showAppBar ? kToolbarHeight : 0,
      //adjust your duration
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
      child: AppBar(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create a new class

```
class MyAppBar extends StatefulWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {


num height = 70.0;
  @override
  _MyAppBarState createState() => _MyAppBarState();

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(height);
}

class _MyAppBarState extends State<MyAppBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onDoubleTap: () {
          // Your logic here
          // You can do any stuff like animating your this appBar
          //e.g: using Opacitiy or Transform and any other Widget depending on what kind of animation you want
          // You can also descrease height by calling widget.height
        },
        child: AppBar(
            //Your logic here
            ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then call it like this

```
 return Scaffold(
  appBar: MyAppBar(),);
```